# Unknown host exception writing to elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, cascading

I'm banging my head with elasticsearch-hadoop. I have this simple cascading job:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inPath = args[ 0 ];
        String outPath = args[ 1 ];
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            AppProps.setApplicationJarClass( properties, Main.class );
            HadoopFlowConnector flowConnector = new HadoopFlowConnector( properties );
            Tap inTap = new Hfs( new TextDelimited( new Fields("url", "title") ), inPath );
            Tap outTap = new EsTap(outPath, new Fields("url", "title"));
            Pipe copyPipe = new Pipe( "copy" );
            FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef()
                    .addSource( copyPipe, inTap )
                    .addTailSink( copyPipe, outTap );
            flowConnector.connect( flowDef ).complete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception running job: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

This should read from the HDFS and write to ES. Running the job halts with this traceback:

```
Exception running job: unhandled exception
cascading.flow.FlowException: unhandled exception
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: BD_C02HD0BPDV11: BD_C02HD0BPDV11
```

Where `BD_C02HD0BPDV11` is the name of my machine, and that should suffice, as I have a local ES installation. Anyway, silly as I am, I tried adding a property to point to my remote ES instance:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("es.nodes","yada-yada.com");
properties.setProperty("es.port","9300");
```

But the same exact error message gets risen (same host name too).

So I'm lost. Is this a configuration error and I'm missing something obvious or I'm lacking a core concept?